# IBM MobileFirst - Android connection error on IPV6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We are using worklight 7 application and getting handshake error on below version.

7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

While app connecting through IPV6 getting below error on android where as it work fine when connect over IPV4.

```
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:99)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.aeknjhzpue.awklahudcn.verify(SourceFile:42)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.vpinofqvte.createSocket(SourceFile:94)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
05-19 18:31:56.840 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
05-19 18:31:56.841 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.ncyludlxhw.run(SourceFile:47)
05-19 18:31:56.841 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
05-19 18:31:56.841 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
05-19 18:31:56.841 16157-16658/com.sampleapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-19 18:31:56.855 16157-16369/com.sampleapp D/wl.certManager: aeknjhzpue.awklahudcn in SourceFile:258 :: Key store cleared.
05-19 18:31:56.860 16157-16369/com.sampleapp D/NONE: Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":500,"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.","invocationContext":null}
05-19 18:31:56.871 16157-16369/com.sampleapp E/NONE: [/apps/services/api/sampleapp/android/query] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
05-19 18:31:56.877 16157-16157/com.sampleapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(311)] "{"status":500,"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.","invocationContext":null}", source: file:///android_asset/wwwBD/default/js/main.js (311)
```

WLClient.properties

```
wlServerProtocol = https
wlServerHost = uatdomain.com
wlServerPort = 443
wlServerContext = /bankcontext/
wlAppId = bankcontext
wlAppVersion = 1.0
GcmSenderId =
enableSettings = false
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions =
webResourcesSize = 5734268
wlUid = nzhTmU3E/iVLhJLzR+BT9w==
wlPlatformVersion = 7.1.0.0
wlMainFilePath = index.html
wlShareCookies =
wlShareUserCert = false
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey =
wlBuildId = 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103
```

Comment: Are configuring wlServerHost property with raw IPv6 address ?

Comment: This is a problem with the SSL handshake.

Comment: Check your mfpclient.properties file - Can you share its contents

Comment: @Srik added the properties in my question. Let us know what needs to be checked whether any fix pack available or any other thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please verify using openssl tool on IPV6 and IPV4 network.

Need to check what exactly return by server on handshake.

Use below command to check and share the result.

*openssl s_client -connet domain:443*

Comment: thanks , we checked and found server is not returning certificate on IPV6. It got resolved now.